# Windows lose focus and appear behind desktop icons

Tags: 22.04, gdm, gnome-shell-extension, focus

On one of my machines I have a problem where **the active windows lose focus and appear behind the desktop icons**. Cf. screenshots.

After playing with Alt-tab it's possible to get out of it, but it's not ideal.
I uninstalled gnome-tweaks, but the issue remains.
Package `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` is installed in order to have icons on the desktop in the first place.

System is: Ubuntu 22.04 with gdm3, gnome-session=ubuntu.

**Workaround 1: NOT WORKING**

1. download the source code from the [repository](https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/tree/master)
2. install it with "ubuntuinstall.sh" script
3. disable "ding" and enable "ubuntuding" extension

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Some of the icon texts are blurred for privacy.

Comment: Interesting, I discovered today that I could place my mouse over the icon and it will bring my window over the icon. I have auto-focus turned on, but that's definitely not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could be a bug in Desktop Icons NG (DING). You mentioned that the issue only happens after the computer is left idle, so maybe the use of LightDM instead of GDM is causing an incompatibility. DING does not specifically say GDM is required. You can create a new issue on their [GitLab issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues).

Comment: My bad, it's not lightdm but gdm3.

Comment: I have the same problem. I setup my middle mouse button to push windows back (Z-wise). When I use that button, my windows go behind the icons. Then trying to capture that window back can be tricky... That being said, that does not happen on all my systems. Just one thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Failed to find a 'legit' way to remove Desktop Icons NG (DING).

```
sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensionsding@rastersoft.com /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensionsding@rastersoft.com_
```

seems to be working ok.